# QGIS connected WMS Server asks evey start for authentification

Tags: qgis, wms, authentication

I connected WMS Server with my QGIS project. There are some which require authentification. This works well with username and password. However, each time I open the QGIS project it asks again for the entry of username and password.

[image]

This appears even though I use a configuration with basic authentication and the right user name and password.
Why does QGIS not use these entries?

[image]